# Magento 2 - Please enter less or equal than 255 symbols valiadtion error in checkout page

Tags: magento2, checkout, onepage-checkout, shipping-address, form-validation

**Magento 2 - `Please enter less or equal than 255 symbols` error message in add new shipping address popup form**

Currently i am getting an error validation message when i open the add new address form to add new shipping address in checkout page.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through a lot of files to track the issue finally i found and implemented this simple approach. And it worked !!

look for this file in vendor folder:

```
/var/www/html/vendor/magento/module-checkout/view/frontend/web/js/view/shipping.js
```

Than look for a method `getPopUp()` and add a this piece of code just before the function return's the popUp variable.

```
/**
 *  keyUp event. 
 */
 var street = ["street[1]", "street[2]", "street[3]"];
 jQuery("#shipping-new-address-form").find(".input-text").each(function(index,element){                    
 if(street.includes(element.name) && element.value ==''){
   jQuery(element).keyup();
   }       
 });
```

Thanks!